# valid ssl certificate is not working on specific port number

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have a website "https://m.abc.com", when I tried to open this website then my website is working fine and I am able to see green lock on address bar, but when I try to open "https://m.abc.com:9090" (where my node server application is running) then I am getting one warning "your connection is not private.. attackers might be trying to steal your information from m.abc.com. NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID " with red warning sign on address bar.  How can I get rid of this warning? And one more thing this is happening randomly on few android mobile only not on iPhone. And on Desktop site I am not getting any warning.

here is the sample code that is writtten in nodejs for https server:

```
var appPort = 9090;

var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/httpd/sslcert/abc.key'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/httpd/sslcert/abc_com.crt')  
};
server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(appPort, function() {
  console.log('HTTPS Server listening at port %d', appPort);
});
```

Comment: Chances are you are running into an issue I did with lets encrypt certs. Are you using something like letsencrypt? Do you have a fullchain.pem/.crt with those files ?  If you do have this fullchain,  try using it instead of the abc_com.cert file.

Example of how not using full chain can cause the issue : 
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-not-trusted-error.html

Comment: @BazG I dont have fullchain.pem/.crt file. instead of this file,  I have abc_com.ca-bundle file. although I checked my domain on "https://www.sslshopper.com" there I am getting result "all the correct intermediate certificates are installed."

Comment: I'm not sure I'm afraid then. Personally I terminate the SSL in nginx (unsure which os you are using) and proxy over to http.  

Example of my SSL termination
http://pastebin.com/UUyhUTAD. This would give you a url of https://example.com/api to route to your api.

Comment: @sumitjainjr did u solve the issue?